# How to materialize data in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, save, materialize, persist

I have the following method which needs to return me a transformed dataframe. `df.sparkSession.sql("SELECT * FROM X")` returns empty DF. How do I materialize data of `df8` so that unpersist doesn't remove all the previous data from dataframes? I am not using Hive so can't use `.saveTableAs`.

```
def doSomething(df: DataFrame): DataFrame ={
val df1: DataFrame = method1(df).persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)

val df2: DataFrame = method2(df1, df)

val df3: DataFrame =
  method3(df2).persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)

 val df4 = method4(df2,
   df3)

val df5: DataFrame = method5(df4)
  .persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)

val df6: DataFrame = method6(df4,
  df5)

val df7: DataFrame = method7(df6)
  .persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)

val df8: DataFrame = method8(df6,
 df7)

df1.unpersist()
df3.unpersist()
df5.unpersist()
df7.unpersist()

 df8.createOrReplaceTempView("X")
df.sparkSession.sql("SELECT * FROM X")
}
```

Comment: Persisting and unpersisting shouldn't affect the results. If it does, you are doing something _terribly_ wrong. Like depending on caching for correctness.

Comment: I am generating these fake data and manipulating my dataframs based on that. If I do not cache the fake generated data then the problem is everytime it does an evaluation, new fake data would be generated that would cause my joins to fail

Comment: It's really hard to know without knowing what those methods are doing to the dataframe. The mistake could be in the implementation of any one of them.